# Reportlab generation of pdf function use

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

Ive been browsing through the ReportLab documentation and looking at solutions here as well: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/52897/reportlab , Im trying to generate a report on a forecasting problem, saving outputs and explanations to the pdf throughout the document. Most of the ReportLab codes are defined as a function (if not all), why? the input to the function is most commonly "request" from what I've seen, can anyone explain why this is and how I would call the final function to create and save the pdf? example :

```
def view_that_returns_pdf(request):

    pdf_value = pdf_buffer.getvalue()
    pdf_buffer.close()
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="some_file.pdf"'

    response.write(pdf_value)
    return response
```

In the code above, how do I call the actual function to write and save the pdf, and what is "request"

Answer (score 0):

That function is from a Django project. More specifically it's a [Django view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/).

The view function takes an incoming HTTP request then returns an HTTP response. The response in this case has the `Content-Disposition` set to "attachment" meaning that the browser will treat it as a download. Alternatively, it could be set to "inline" which will open in the browser.